# \use:c already defined—command invoking \glsaddkey

Tags: glossaries, expl3

I'm trying to encode in `\GlsAddKey`, the creation of keys using `\glsaddkey` with preset fields. In other words, what I did for `bar`, I'd like to be able to do for an arbitrary key.

PS: I don't understand `\glsaddstoragekey`, so I left it there in case someone wants to comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makenoidxglossaries

  \glsaddstoragekey*{foo}% key
  {NA}% default value
  {\glsentryfoo}% command analogous to \glsentrytext

  \glsaddkey*{bar}% key
  {NA}% default value
  {\glsentrybar}% command analogous to \glsentrytext
  {\Glsentrybar}% command analogous to \Glsentrytext
  {\glsbar}% command analogous to \glstext
  {\Glsbar}% command analogous to \Glstext
  {\GLSbar}% command analogous to \GLStext

  \newglossaryentry{x}
  {
    name={X},
    description={next letter ??},
    % description={letter \glsfoo{x}}%,
    bar={Y}
  }

  \newglossaryentry{y}
  {
    name={Y},
    description={next letter \glsbar{y}},
    % description={next letter ??},
    bar={Z}
  }

  \ExplSyntaxOn
  
  \NewDocumentCommand\GlsAddKey{m}
  {
      \glsaddkey*
      {#1}% key
      {NA}% default value
      {\use:c{glsentry#1}}% command analogous to \glsentrytext
      {\use:c{Glsentry#1}}% command analogous to \Glsentrytext
      {\use:c{gls#1}}% command analogous to \glstext
      {\use:c{Gls#1}}% command analogous to \Glstext
      {\use:c{GLS#1}}% command analogous to \GLStext
  }
  
  \ExplSyntaxOff

%  \GlsAddKey{qux} % LaTeX Error: Command \use:c already defined.
%  \newglossaryentry{z}
%  {
%    name={Z},
%    description={next letter \glsqux{z}},
%%    description={next letter ??},
%    qux={(none)}
%  }

  
\begin{document}

%\gls{x}
%\glsfoo{x} % ERROR

\gls{y}
%\glsbar{y}

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `\glsaddkey*{bar}`, the `glossaries` package does something like

```
\newcommand{\glsentrybar}{...}
```

for each of the arguments consisting of a command name. Of course

```
\newcommand{\use:c{glsentryqux}}
```

will fail exactly in the way you see from the error message. You need to provide a single already formed token. A fast (but not so nice) method is to do the necessary expansions in advance.

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand\GlsAddKey{m}
  {
   \use:x
    {
     \exp_not:N \glsaddkey*
      {#1}% key
      {NA}% default value
      {\exp_not:c{glsentry#1}}% command analogous to \glsentrytext
      {\exp_not:c{Glsentry#1}}% command analogous to \Glsentrytext
      {\exp_not:c{gls#1}}% command analogous to \glstext
      {\exp_not:c{Gls#1}}% command analogous to \Glstext
      {\exp_not:c{GLS#1}}% command analogous to \GLStext
    }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

A more `expl3` style version:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makenoidxglossaries

\glsaddstoragekey*{foo}% key
  {NA}% default value
  {\glsentryfoo}% command analogous to \glsentrytext

\glsaddkey*{bar}% key
  {NA}% default value
  {\glsentrybar}% command analogous to \glsentrytext
  {\Glsentrybar}% command analogous to \Glsentrytext
  {\glsbar}% command analogous to \glstext
  {\Glsbar}% command analogous to \Glstext
  {\GLSbar}% command analogous to \GLStext

\newglossaryentry{x}
  {
    name={X},
    description={letter \glsentryfoo{x}}%,
    bar={Y}
  }

\newglossaryentry{y}
  {
    name={Y},
    description={next letter \glsbar{y}},
    bar={Z}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOn
  
\NewDocumentCommand\GlsAddKey{O{NA}m}
 {
  \erwann_glsaddkey:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \erwann_glsaddkey:nn
 {
  \__erwann_glsaddkey:nnccccc
   { #2 } % key
   { #1 } % default value
   { glsentry#2 }
   { Glsentry#2 }
   { gls#2 }
   { Gls#2 }
   { GLS#2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__erwann_glsaddkey:nnNNNNN
 {
  \glsaddkey* { #1 } { #2 } #3 #4 #5 #6 #7
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__erwann_glsaddkey:nnNNNNN { nnccccc }
  
\ExplSyntaxOff

\GlsAddKey{qux} % LaTeX Error: Command \use:c already defined.

\newglossaryentry{z}
  {
   name={Z},
   description={next letter \glsqux{z}},
   qux={(none)}
  }

  
\begin{document}

\gls{x}
%\glsfoo{x} % ERROR

\gls{y}
\glsbar{y}

\gls{z}
\glsqux{z}

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```